# Warnings regarding providing key in map function but I already have one and warnings regarding whitespace

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key, warnings, whitespace

I am encountering these warnings I need to eliminate them.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Summary`. 

    in tr (at Summary.js:46)
    in Summary (at Main.js:323)
    in StepForm (at App.js:8)
    in div (at App.js:7)
    in div (at App.js:6)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tr>. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code.

    in tr (at Summary.js:46)
    in tbody (at Summary.js:44)
    in table (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (at Summary.js:32)
    in Summary (at Main.js:323)
    in StepForm (at App.js:8)
    in div (at App.js:7)
    in div (at App.js:6)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

4/11/2020
Regarding the key, I have already included it on my code, but still receiving the warning message, please see code below:

```
<tbody>
    {postArray.map(postArr=>
        <tr><td key = {postArr.txNumber}></td>
            <td>{postArr.accountNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.amount}</td>
            <td>{postArr.qNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.txNumber}</td>
            {/* <td><button >Edit</button></td> */}
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.editOne(postArr.txNumber)}>Edit</button></td>
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.deleteTx(postArr.txNumber)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Could you post the map code of your Summary?

Comment: Posted map code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were wrong when you mapped data:

**First prediction:**

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

You must set the key value when mapping:

for example:

```
cols.map(colData => {
   return <td key={colData.key}>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
});
```

**Second prediction:**

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear
>   as a child of . Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace
>   between tags on each line of your source code.

You need to clear the extra free space (`tr & td`)

for example:

```
return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
```

to

```
return <tr key={item.id}>{cells}</tr>;
```

**And finally, together:**

```
    ...

    if (this.props.rows.length > 0) {
              return data.map(item => {
                  var cells = cols.map(colData => {
                      return <td key={colData.key}>{item[colData.key]}</td>;
                  });
                  return <tr key={item.id}>{cells}</tr>;
              });
        }

    ...
```

**Edited:**

You need to set the key value and clear the extra free space for the parent `tr`

```
<tr key={postArr.txNumber}>
```

**And you have to change:**

```
<tbody>
    {postArray.map(postArr=>
        <tr><td key = {postArr.txNumber}></td>
            <td>{postArr.accountNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.amount}</td>
            <td>{postArr.qNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.txNumber}</td>
            {/* <td><button >Edit</button></td> */}
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.editOne(postArr.txNumber)}>Edit</button></td>
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.deleteTx(postArr.txNumber)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>)}
</tbody>
```

to:

```
<tbody>
    {postArray.map(postArr=> (
        <tr key={postArr.txNumber}>
            <td>{postArr.accountNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.amount}</td>
            <td>{postArr.qNumber}</td>
            <td>{postArr.txNumber}</td>
            {/* <td><button >Edit</button></td> */}
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.editOne(postArr.txNumber)}>Edit</button></td>
            <td><button className="txnbuttonsmall" onClick={()=>this.props.deleteTx(postArr.txNumber)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
   ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Regarding the whitespace already resolved, thanks.   For the key I am still encountering warnings, I have posted the map code.

Comment: @Concorde. Ok. I made the necessary changes in the edit section. Please give you a green check and a score if it helps. Thankful